# Python date string mm/dd/yyyy to datetime

Tags: python, string, datetime

I have to write a program where I take stocks from yahoo finance and print out certain information for the site.  One of the pieces of data is the date.  I need to take a date such as 3/21/2012 and converter to the following format: Mar 21, 2012.

Here is my code for the entire project.

```
def getStockData(company="GOOG"):

    baseurl ="http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={0}&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgvj1pp2owern&e=.csv"

    url = baseurl.format(company)
    conn = u.urlopen(url)
    content = conn.readlines()
    data = content[0].decode("utf-8")
    data = data.split(",")
    date = data[2][1:-1]
    date_new = datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%B[0:3] %d, %Y")
    print("The last trade for",company, "was", data[1],"and the change was", data[4],"on", date_new)


company = input("What company would you like to look up?")
getStockData(company)


co = ["VOD.L", "AAPL", "YHOO", "S", "T"]
for company in co:
    getStockData(company)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really specify what about your code is not working (i.e., what output are you getting that you don't expect? What error message are you getting, if any?). However, I suspect your problem is with this part:

```
strftime('%B[0:3] %d, %Y')
```

Since Python won't do what you think with that attempt to slice `'%B'`. You should instead use  `'%b'`, which [as noted in the documentation for strftime()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), corresponds to the locale-abbreviated month name.

---

**EDIT**

Here is a fully functional script based on what you posted above with my suggested modifications:

```
import urllib2 as u
from datetime import datetime

def getStockData(company="GOOG"):
    baseurl ="http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={0}&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgvj1pp2owern&e=.csv"

    url = baseurl.format(company)
    conn = u.urlopen(url)
    content = conn.readlines()
    data = content[0].decode("utf-8")
    data = data.split(",")
    date = data[2][1:-1]
    date_new = datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%b %d, %Y")
    print("The last trade for",company, "was", data[1],"and the change was", data[4],"on", date_new)

for company in ["VOD.L", "AAPL", "YHOO", "S", "T"]:
    getStockData(company)
```

The output of this script is:

```
The last trade for VOD.L was 170.00 and the change was -1.05 on Mar 06, 2012
The last trade for AAPL was 530.26 and the change was -2.90 on Mar 06, 2012
The last trade for YHOO was 14.415 and the change was -0.205 on Mar 06, 2012
The last trade for S was 2.39 and the change was -0.04 on Mar 06, 2012
The last trade for T was 30.725 and the change was -0.265 on Mar 06, 2012
```

For what it's worth, I'm running this on Python 2.7.1. I also had the line `from __future__ import print_function` to make this compatible with the Python3 print function you appear to be using.

Comment: THis is the error that I am getting:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\I211\a4.py", line 44, in <module>
    getStockData(company)
  File "F:\I211\a4.py", line 39, in getStockData
    date_new = datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%B[0:3] %d, %Y")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'"

Comment: @user1251230: It sounds like you have a line like `import datetime` in your file. Change that to `from datetime import datetime`, which will import the `datetime` class as `datetime` rather than the datetime module.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Check out [Dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil). You can use it to parse a string into python datetime object and then print that object using strftime.</strike>

I've since come to a conclusion that auto detection of datetime value is not always a good idea. It's much better to use `strptime` and specify what format you want.